# GRASS GIS in OSGeo Live - cannot add extension

Tags: grass-gis, ubuntu

I use GRASS GIS in OSGeoLive v14 on Ubuntu in virtual machine (Oracle Virtual Box). When I try add any extension, it is giving me a FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'svn'.
I note that grass-dev is installed.

Anyone know how to solve it?

Full Shell message:

```
*(Fri Sep 30 09:50:49 2022)                                                      
g.extension extension=r.lake.series                                             
Fetching <r.lake.series> from GRASS GIS Addons repository (be patient)...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/scripts/g.extension", line 2350, in
<module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/scripts/g.extension", line 2330, in
main
    install_extension(source=source, url=url, xmlurl=xmlurl,
branch=branch)
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/scripts/g.extension", line 873, in
install_extension
    ret1, new_modules_ext, new_files_ext, tmp_dir =
install_extension_std_platforms(extension,
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/scripts/g.extension", line 1523, in
install_extension_std_platforms
    download_source_code(source=source, url=url, name=name,
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/scripts/g.extension", line 1454, in
download_source_code
    download_source_code_official_github(url, name, outdev,
directory)
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/scripts/g.extension", line 1336, in
download_source_code_official_github
    if grass.call(['svn', 'export',
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/etc/python/grass/script/core.py",
line 74, in call
    return Popen(*args, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/etc/python/grass/script/core.py",
line 63, in __init__
    subprocess.Popen.__init__(self, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in
__init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn,
close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in
_execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg,
err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'svn'
(Fri Sep 30 09:50:50 2022) Command finished (1 sec)*
```

Comment: The new OSGeoLive 15 is on the way. Please give it a try:
 http://download.osgeo.org/livedvd/releases/15.0/osgeolive-15.0rc3-amd64.vmdk.7z